# How to use NumPy to create two subarrays from the randomized contents of a source array?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, random

I have an array A, I want to create arrays B and C.

Basically, I want to randomly find 100 elements in A, put them in B and the rest in C.

If I use numpy.random.choice I can easily create B by just extracting all the elements in A that match the indices in the random list, but I would have to go through A again in order to find all the values that are not in B and put them in C. This works, but maybe there is a built-in function that can do this for me.

Is there a cheaper way?

Comment: Perhaps other users will be able to come up with a brilliant solution to this, but my bet is that using a masking operation is the way to go. 
Generate a boolean array `mask = np.ones(A.shape[0], dtype=bool)`; use your random generator to set elements to False; `C = A[mask]`; `B = A[~mask]`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could select elements from the array using indices and create a boolean mask like this:

```
indices = np.random.choice(len(a),3) # pick indices at random from array a
mask = np.ones(a.shape,dtype=bool)   # create boolean mask
mask[indices] = False                
a[indices]     # random elements from array 
a[mask]        # rest of array
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this, numpy inbuilt function

```
import numpy as np
import random
a = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]);
b = np.array(random.sample(a.values,3));
c = np.setdiff1d(a,b)
```